# exclude a folder from matlab recursive file search

Tags: matlab

When searching with MATLAB's file search (Ctrl + f from the "Current Folder" window) I'd like to perform a recursive search which excludes my ".git" folder.  Including it takes time and includes a lot of false positives.  I've tried just shift and click on only those folders I'd like to search but MATLAB (2015b) won't support this.

Answer (score 0):

Far from a perfect solution, but you can choose to "include only file type(s):"

```
*.m, *.mlx
```

[image: Matlab Find Files dialogue]

Your `.git` folder should not contain any of these.
For me, this has increased search speed dramatically.